# How do I iterate through all the viewholders in a recyclerview adapter?

Tags: android

I have a fragment with a RecyclerView with some records databound to it.  Each record is a product that is part of a "combo" special (bud light, miller light, tuna sandwich, etc.).  Basically, the customer is selecting products for a combo (6 domestic beers, 2 sandwiches and 1 drink, etc.) Each product has a set of "product groupings" (domestic beer, beer, sandwich, lunch item, etc.).  Next to each item I have a plus and minus button to add/subtract items into the shopping cart.  Inside my adapter, I need to check if the customer has selected all of his "domestic beers" or both of his "sandwiches".  if certain group quantity totals values are over the total number of that group allowed in the combo, I need to disable the add buttons for those items.

ComboItemsAdapter.java

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
...
itemHolder.tvQuantity.setText("0");
...
itemHolder.buy_subtract_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
        checkTotals(); 
     }
}
itemHolder.buy_add_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
        checkTotals(); 
     }
}

}

private void checkTotals(){
//here I want to check some stuff, and if that stuff is true I want to disable all the buttons in that viewholder, some buttons will be disabled, some won't
}
```

So my question is what is the best way to iterate through each row in my recyclerview/adapter in the checkTotals() function and disable the appropriate buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the itemHolder to the checkTotal() function and under that function, perform your condition statement to enable or disable the click.

Comment: That won't work because I have to disable/enable multiple buttons inside different viewholders depending on a running total.

Comment: What do you mean by different viewholders?

Comment: I need to iterate through all the rows in the adapter and disable certain buttons.  There is a plus and minus button on each row.  If I reach a total, I need to disable the plus buttons on certain rows and not others.

Comment: The above logic works preety well for what you have said.

Comment: but only for that single row, not for all the rows...unless I'm misunderstanding you.  Clicking a single row should then check every row and disable certain buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Best place to check for a condition is inside `onBindViewHolder` itself!
Since you going to adjust `UI` of each `row` based on some condition, you have to do it in `onBindViewHolder`; since it is the method that get called when a row is recycled and going to be assigned new data..

P.S: However be aware that doing complex calculation inside `onBindViewHolder` is not advised as this method must executed as fast as possible, if your condition is a complex one please do it inside your adapter constructor and cache the result for each row.. Later just adjust your view inside `onBindViewHolder` based on the result.

Comment: however each holder contains a plus and minus button, the calculation has to occur each time one of those buttons is clicked.  Some buttons will be disabled and some will not based on a running total for groupings of items.

Comment: I get what you want to do but your description is not clear, can you clearly describe what you want to do instead of just abstract idea?

Comment: I need to access all the buttons on each row in my recycler view and disable some and not others.

Comment: Ok, You should do this in onBindViewHolder of RecyclerAdapter. This is the only correct way to edit views..